# Why doesn't JUnit test work in Play 2.3.1/Java project?

Tags: java, junit, playframework, junit4, playframework-2.3

In my brand new Play 2.3.1 Java application, I write the first tests, but they don't work at all. I launch `activator test`, a simple test class put directly in the default package in the `test` directory isn't reached.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestTest {

    @Test
    public void testTest() {
        Assert.assertEquals(true, false);
    }
}
```

When I launch `activator testOnly TestTest`, I have the following output :

```
[info] Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0
[info] No tests to run for test:testOnly
[success] Totaltime: 6 s, completed 11 juil. 2014 09:08:38
```

What could be the cause ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me so your issue need more details to have a useful solution.

Run `activator --version` to check the version. Mine is based on sbt launcher 0.13.5.

```
➜  sandbox  activator --version
sbt launcher version 0.13.5
```

It doesn't say much about the version of activator itself (however activator 1.2.x is likely sbt 0.13.5). Upgrade if yours is older.

Ran `activator new my-brand-new-play-app play-java` to create a Play/Java application.

```
➜  sandbox  activator new my-brand-new-play-app play-java

Fetching the latest list of templates...

OK, application "my-brand-new-play-app" is being created using the "play-java" template.

To run "my-brand-new-play-app" from the command line, "cd my-brand-new-play-app" then:
/Users/jacek/sandbox/my-brand-new-play-app/activator run

To run the test for "my-brand-new-play-app" from the command line, "cd my-brand-new-play-app" then:
/Users/jacek/sandbox/my-brand-new-play-app/activator test

To run the Activator UI for "my-brand-new-play-app" from the command line, "cd my-brand-new-play-app" then:
/Users/jacek/sandbox/my-brand-new-play-app/activator ui
```

I then copied your `TestTest` class to `test/TestTest.java` with no changes:

```
➜  my-brand-new-play-app  cat test/TestTest.java
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestTest {

    @Test
    public void testTest() {
    Assert.assertEquals(true, false);
    }
}
```

With the only change to create the test file, I ran `activator test`. After a whole lot of file downloads, the results was:

```
➜  my-brand-new-play-app  activator test
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/my-brand-new-play-app/project
[info] Set current project to my-brand-new-play-app (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/my-brand-new-play-app/)
[info] ApplicationTest
[info] + ApplicationTest.simpleCheck
[info] + ApplicationTest.renderTemplate
[info]
[info]
[info] Total for test ApplicationTest
[info] Finished in 0.015 seconds
[info] 2 tests, 0 failures, 0 errors
[error] Test IntegrationTest.test failed: <''> should contain the String:<'Your new application is ready.'>, took 1.742 sec
[info] IntegrationTest
[info] x IntegrationTest.test
[error] sbt.ForkMain$ForkError: <''> should contain the String:<'Your new application is ready.'>
[error]     at org.fest.assertions.Fail.failure(Fail.java:228)
[error]     at org.fest.assertions.Assert.failure(Assert.java:149)
[error]     at org.fest.assertions.StringAssert.contains(StringAssert.java:73)
[error]     at IntegrationTest$1.invoke(IntegrationTest.java:23)
[error]     at IntegrationTest$1.invoke(IntegrationTest.java:20)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.running(Helpers.java:549)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.running(Helpers.java:536)
[error]     at IntegrationTest.test(IntegrationTest.java:20)
[info]
[info]
[info] Total for test IntegrationTest
[info] Finished in 0.005 seconds
[info] 1 tests, 1 failures, 0 errors
[error] Test TestTest.testTest failed: expected:<true> but was:<false>, took 0.0 sec
[info] TestTest
[info] x TestTest.testTest
[error] sbt.ForkMain$ForkError: expected:<true> but was:<false>
[error]     at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
[error]     at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
[error]     at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
[error]     at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
[error]     at TestTest.testTest(TestTest.java:8)
[info]
[info]
[info] Total for test TestTest
[info] Finished in 0.002 seconds
[info] 1 tests, 1 failures, 0 errors
[error] Failed: Total 4, Failed 2, Errors 0, Passed 2
[error] Failed tests:
[error]     IntegrationTest
[error]     TestTest
[error] (test:test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Jul 10, 2014 11:27:04 PM
```

The `TestTest` test was indeed executed.

I also executed the TestTest only with `'testOnly TestTest'` as follows:

```
➜  my-brand-new-play-app  activator 'testOnly TestTest'
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/my-brand-new-play-app/project
[info] Set current project to my-brand-new-play-app (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/my-brand-new-play-app/)
[error] Test TestTest.testTest failed: expected:<true> but was:<false>, took 0.003 sec
[info] TestTest
[info] x TestTest.testTest
[error] sbt.ForkMain$ForkError: expected:<true> but was:<false>
[error]     at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
[error]     at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
[error]     at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
[error]     at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
[error]     at TestTest.testTest(TestTest.java:8)
[info]
[info]
[info] Total for test TestTest
[info] Finished in 0.012 seconds
[info] 1 tests, 1 failures, 0 errors
[error] Failed: Total 1, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 0
[error] Failed tests:
[error]     TestTest
[error] (test:testOnly) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Jul 10, 2014 11:29:37 PM
```

All in all, it worked fine. I'm unsure what might be the issue of yours exactly since I followed your steps as closely as the description of the issue allowed.

Comment: Ok, I restarted my project from scratch and it worked. I suppose I did something bad.

Answer (score 5):

Ran into the same issue where no tests were found; `activator clean` resolved the problem.

Comment: It fixes, but what is the cause?

Answer (score 0):

The solution with `activator clean` sometimes doesn't work when Eclipse is running. Closing Eclipse and then peforming `activator clean` afterwards worked for me.